# Nested if statement not working to create a Risk Log

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, mslists

I am trying to move risk logs to MS list and have encountered issues with the if nested statements. I have tried different variations of the formula below.

The formula seems to work with half of the statements but when all statements are input it crashes.

I am calculating from two columns `([Initial Likelihood]+[Initial Impact])` with the following criteria.

- Almost Certain + insignificant=5
- Rare + significant=5
- Almost Certain + minor=10
- Unlikely + significant=10
- Likely + moderate=12
- Possible + Major=12
- Almost certain + moderate=15
- Possible + Significant=15
- Likely + major=16
- Almost certain + major=20
- Likely + significant=20
- Almost certain + significant=25

This is the latest formula I have used.

```
=IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare", [Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"1",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely", [Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"2",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare", [Initial Impact]="Minor"),"2",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible", [Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"3",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare", [Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"3","")))))&
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely", [Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"4",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely", [Initial Impact]="Minor"),"4",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare", [Initial Impact]="Major"),"4",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain", [Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"5",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare", [Initial Impact]="Significant"),"5","")))))&
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible", [Initial Impact]="Minor"),"6",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely", [Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"6",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely", [Initial Impact]="Minor"),"8",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely", [Initial Impact]="Major"),"8",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible", [Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"9","")))))&
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain", [Initial Impact]="Minor"),"10",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely", [Initial Impact]="Significant"),"10",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely", [Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"12",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible", [Initial Impact]="Major"),"12",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain", [Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"15","")))))&
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible", [Initial Impact]="Significant"),"15",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely", [Initial Impact]="Major"),"16",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain", [Initial Impact]="Major"),"20",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely", [Initial Impact]="Significant"),"20",
IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain", [Initial Impact]="Significant"),"25",""))))))
```

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula just contains additional closing bracket at the end. Try removing by additional bracket from end.

Try below formula, it should work:

```
=IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare",[Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"1",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"2",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare",[Initial Impact]="Minor"),"2",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible",[Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"3",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare",[Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"3","")))))&IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely",[Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"4",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Initial Impact]="Minor"),"4",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare",[Initial Impact]="Major"),"4",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain",[Initial Impact]="Insignificant"),"5",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Rare",[Initial Impact]="Significant"),"5","")))))&IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible",[Initial Impact]="Minor"),"6",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"6",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely",[Initial Impact]="Minor"),"8",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Initial Impact]="Major"),"8",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible",[Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"9","")))))&IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain",[Initial Impact]="Minor"),"10",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Initial Impact]="Significant"),"10",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely",[Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"12",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible",[Initial Impact]="Major"),"12",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain",[Initial Impact]="Moderate"),"15","")))))&IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Possible",[Initial Impact]="Significant"),"15",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely",[Initial Impact]="Major"),"16",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain",[Initial Impact]="Major"),"20",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Likely",[Initial Impact]="Significant"),"20",IF(AND([Initial Likelihood]="Almost Certain",[Initial Impact]="Significant"),"25","")))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has now resolve my issue.